# Expression has changed after it was checked - Typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have body in html as:

```
<tbody [ngClass]="IsDisableRowSelectValidation == false ? 'row-select-validate' : ''" #formScroll [scrollTop]="formScroll.scrollHeight" *ngIf="PersonList">
```

Getting error as below:

```
 Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'scrollTop: 128'. Current value: 'scrollTop: 0'.
```

I am not sure what is the cause of this error and how to prevent this kind of error.

I really appreciate the help. Thank you!

Comment: Please refer about this [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-debugging/)

Comment: Take a look to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O47uUnJjbJc&list=PL1w1q3fL4pmi8SydlCdMdm7kCbHi-7wpS